# Special charactes in query parameter

Tags: character-encoding

I am using 1 search option on my form. Here when i pass any special
characters like `& or $` it does not hold that request parameter in the search box yeah but it is processing my request of search.

Answer (score 2):

You need to [URL encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the values in the query string.

Comment: How i can use it in my spring controller?

Comment: I am already using <%@ page language="java" errorPage="/error.jsp" pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8" %> in my jsp so if i use URLEncode in my controller won't it be 2 times encoding my query param

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Java but I used code similar to that below when sending user text to Google translate via Google URL parameter. (Assume values for myText, myURL, and myTextURL are already assigned.)

```
<script>
function transfix(isURL,form) {
    if(isURL) window.open( myURL     + encodeURIComponent(myText) );
    else      window.open( myTextURL + decodeURIComponent(myText) );  
}
</script>

<form target=_blank id="translate" name="translate">

<input type="button" value="Text" onclick="transfix(false,this.form)">
<input type="button" value="URL"  onclick="transfix(true,this.form)"> 

</form>
```